# Getting which radiobuttons is selected and hiding inputs in Asp.net MVC (maybe with jquery?)

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, razor, model-view-controller

This are my actual code on view, the jquery code seems that it's not working.

Already tried a couple things like js/jquery different approachs on code(mostly tries was with different syntax of both languages) but nothing worked yet. I want that when the CbUsuario got checked the Cnpj input get hidden, I can change the html inputs to razor inputs too if needed.

Keep in mind that I'm pretty newbie in javascript/jquery and mvc aswell.

```
@model Collab.Domain.Entities.Usuario

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Registrar";
}

<div class="limiter">
    <div class="container-form">
        <div class="wrap-login">

        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            <span class="cadastro-form-title">
                Cadastro
            </span>

            <p>@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</p>

            <div class="wrap-input">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="Nome">
                <span class="focus-input" data-placeholder="Nome"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="CPF">
                <span class="focus-input" data-placeholder="CPF"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input" id="Cnpj">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="Cnpj" id="Cnpj">
                <span class="focus-input" data-placeholder="CNPJ" id="Cnpj"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input validate-input" data-validate="Insira um email válido">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="Email">
                <span class="focus-input" data-placeholder="E-mail"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="wrap-input validate-input" data-validate="Preencha o campo senha">
                <span class="btn-show-pass">
                    <i class="zmdi zmdi-eye"></i>
                </span>
                <input class="input" type="password" name="Senha">
                <span class="focus-input" data-placeholder="Senha"></span>
            </div>

            <span>Tipo da conta:</span>

            <div>
                <input type="radio" name="Cb" value="Usuario" id="CbUsuario"> Usuario<br>
                <input type="radio" name="Cb" value="Pesquisador" id="CbPesquisador"> Pesquisador<br>
                <input type="radio" name="Cb" value="Investidor" id="CbInvestidor"> Investidor
            </div>

            <div class="container-form-btn">
                <div class="wrap-form-btn">
                    <div class="form-bgbtn"></div>
                    <button class="form-btn">
                        Cadastrar
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>




        }

    </div>
</div>
```

```
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
    @Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Cb").change(function () {
                var checkedradio = $('[name="Cb"]:radio:checked').val();
                if (checkedradio.val() == "Usuario") {
                    $("#Cnpj").hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting pretty close, but there's a couple things to adjust to get this functioning.  First off, your change event is working off of an ID selector, when you're looking for a name selector.  You've already got that within the change callback, so re-using that will get the event firing correctly:

`$("#Cb").change()` becomes `$("[name=Cb]:radio").change()`

Next, you're getting the value of the checked radio button then attempting to call `.val()` on that string value, which throws an error.  If you update your `if` block to just compare the result of the value check on the previous line, you should be good.  After changes, it should look like this:

```
$("[name=Cb]:radio").change(function() {
    var checkedValue = $('[name="Cb"]:radio:checked').val();
    if (checkedValue == "Usuario") {
      $("#Cnpj").hide();
    } else {
      $("#Cnpj").show();
    }
});
```

I added in an `else` block so choosing other radio buttons will show the hidden textbox, so it's not gone forever after checking the `Usuario` radio button as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="Cb" value="Usuario" id="CbUsuario"> Usuario<br>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="Cb" value="Pesquisador" id="CbPesquisador"> Pesquisador<br>
    <input type="radio" class="radio" name="Cb" value="Investidor" id="CbInvestidor"> Investidor
```

and JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $(".radio").change(function () {
                var checkedradio = $('[name="Cb"]:radio:checked').val();
                if (checkedradio == "Usuario") {
                    $("#Cnpj").hide();
                }
                else {
                    $("#Cnpj").show();
                }
      });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () { 
   $("input[name='Cb']").change(function(e){   
      if($(this).val() == 'Usuario') {
          $('#Cnpj').css('visibility','hidden');
      } else {
          $('#Cnpj').css('visibility','visible');
      }

  }); 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-cid="Cnpj" class="wrap-input" id="Cnpj">
                <input class="input" type="text" name="Cnpj" id="Cnpj">
                <span class="focus-input" data-placeholder="CNPJ" id="Cnpj"></span>
            </div>
            
<div>
                <input data-cid="Usuario" type="radio" name="Cb" value="Usuario" id="CbUsuario"> Usuario<br>
                <input type="radio" name="Cb" value="Pesquisador" id="CbPesquisador"> Pesquisador<br>
                <input type="radio" name="Cb" value="Investidor" id="CbInvestidor"> Investidor
            </div>
```